# Difference between capture and identification in browser files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create my own browser file for my ASP.net MVC application. But I'm not clear about the difference of the "capture" and the "identification" element within a gateway or browser element of the browser file. Both can have an userAgent-element defining a regular expression:

```
<identification>
    <userAgent match="iPad" />
</identification>
<capture>
    <userAgent match="iPad" />
</capture>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**capture**

Defines information about what additional header, userAgent or capability elements to use to capture information about the browser. This is useful when trying to detect new browsers that were not available when the .NET Framework 2.0 was released. To capture values, a browser definition can include regular expression captures in the match attribute of any identification element. For example, the following userAgent element defined in the IE.browser file captures the height of the screen in pixels from the user agent request header.

A browser definition might also need to capture additional information by scanning request headers that are not used to distinguish the browser class. For example, the following capture element captures the number of soft keys for an OpenWave cellular phone. Soft keys display menus and commands when you press corresponding hardware buttons on Windows Mobile-based SmartPhones:

```
<capture>
    <header name="HTTP_X_UP_DEVCAP_NUMSOFTKEYS" 
            match="(?'softkeys'\d+)" />
</capture>
```

The capture element contains no attributes.

The capture element can contain zero or more of the following child elements:

```
header

userAgent

capability
```

**identification**

Defines information about how to identify this browser from the incoming request.

The identification element contains no attributes.

The identification element can contain one or more of the following child elements:

```
header

userAgent

capability
```